# Folding flatMap/bind over a list of functions (a.k.a. Name That Combinator!)

Tags: scala, haskell, combinators

In the process of writing a simple RPN calculator, I have the following type aliases:

```scala
type Stack = List[Double]
type Operation = Stack => Option[Stack]
```

... and I have written a curious-looking line of Scala code:

```scala
val newStack = operations.foldLeft(Option(stack)) { _ flatMap _ }
```

This takes an initial `stack` of values and applies a list of `operations` to that stack.  Each operation may fail (i.e. yields an `Option[Stack]`) so I sequence them with `flatMap`.  The thing that's somewhat unusual about this (in my mind) is that I'm folding over a list of monadic functions, rather than folding over a list of data.

I want to know if there's a standard function that captures this "fold-bind" behavior.  When I'm trying to play the "Name That Combinator" game, Hoogle is usually my friend, so I tried the same mental exercise in Haskell:

```haskell
foldl (>>=) (Just stack) operations
```

The types here are:

```haskell
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

So the type of my mystery `foldl (>>=)` combinator, after making the types of `foldl` and `(>>=)` line up, should be:

```haskell
mysteryCombinator :: Monad m => m a -> [a -> m a] -> m a
```

... which is again what we'd expect.  My problem is that searching Hoogle for a function with that type yields no results.  I tried a couple other permutations that I thought might be reasonable: `a -> [a -> m a] -> m a` (i.e. starting with a non-monadic value), `[a -> m a] -> m a -> m a` (i.e. with arguments flipped), but no luck there either.  So my question is, does anybody know a standard name for my mystery "fold-bind" combinator?

Comment: I would recommend against using this implementation of the combinator; I believe most implementations of `(>>=)` are intended to be used in a right-associative manner, so there's a good chance this could cause bad performance problems (like a left-associative stack of `(++)`s does).

Comment: @ehird - I don't think I understand...  How else would you propose applying a sequence of `[a -> m a]` operations, in left-to-right order, to some starting `a` or `m a` value?  Also, keep in mind I'm not asking a language-specific question; performance characteristics will differ between Scala and Haskell (you could assume I'm using `foldl'` for strictness).  All I really care about is whether this thing has a well-known name.

Comment: I think @ehird's point is that `foldr` can be more efficient since that can stop early (in case of a `Nothing`, for example).

Comment: @ehird If he uses foldl, then the right associativity of >>= is preserved. For instance, `foldl (>>=) Nothing [a,b,c]`  is like `Nothing >>= (a >>= (b >>= c)))`. Though I would still use foldl' if nothing else prevented me from doing so.

Comment: @Ingo: Yes, you're right; my mistake.

Comment: @Ingo No, `foldl (>>=) Nothing [a,b,c] = ((Nothing >>= a) >>= b) >>= c`.

Comment: @Daniel oops, my fault. Anyway, isn't (a >>= b) >>= c == a >>= (b >>= c) one of the monad laws? Hence, the associativity of >>= is not really important. Only thing that matters is the order of a,b,c and it's the same regardless of associativity.

Comment: @Ingo Almost. The law is `(a >>= b) >>= c === a >>= \x -> (b x >>= c)`, more readable `(a >>= b) >>= c === a >>= (b >=> c)`, even better `(a >=> b) >=> c === a >=> (b >=> c)`. So yes, the end result is the same, but the performance can be much different. Try `foldX (>=>) return (const Nothing : replicate 1000000 Just) True` for X in {r,l,l'}.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`a -> m a` is just a *Kleisli arrow* with the argument and result types both being *a*. [Control.Monad.(>=>)](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-) composes two Kleisli arrows:

```
(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> a -> m c
```

Think `flip (.)`, but for Kleisli arrows instead of functions.

So we can split this combinator into two parts, the composition and the "application":

```
composeParts :: (Monad m) => [a -> m a] -> a -> m a
composeParts = foldr (>=>) return

mysteryCombinator :: (Monad m) => m a -> [a -> m a] -> m a
mysteryCombinator m fs = m >>= composeParts fs
```

Now, `(>=>)` and `flip (.)` are related in a deeper sense than just being analogous; both the function arrow, `(->)`, and the data type wrapping a Kleisli arrow, `Kleisli`, are instances of [Control.Category.Category](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Category.html). So if we were to import that module, we could in fact rewrite `composeParts` as:

```
composeParts :: (Category cat) => [cat a a] -> cat a a
composeParts = foldr (>>>) id
```

`(>>>)` (defined in Control.Category) is just a nicer way of writing as `flip (.)`.

---

So, there's no standard name that I know of, but it's just a generalisation of composing a list of functions. There's an `Endo a` type in the standard library that wraps `a -> a` and has a [Monoid](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Monoid.html#t:Monoid) instance where `mempty` is `id` and `mappend` is `(.)`; we can generalise this to any Category:

```
newtype Endo cat a = Endo { appEndo :: cat a a }

instance (Category cat) => Monoid (Endo cat a) where
  mempty = Endo id
  mappend (Endo f) (Endo g) = Endo (f . g)
```

We can then implement `composeParts` as:

```
composeParts = appEndo . mconcat . map Endo . reverse
```

which is just `mconcat . reverse` with some wrapping. However, we can avoid the `reverse`, which is there because the instance uses `(.)` rather than `(>>>)`, by using the `Dual a` Monoid, which just transforms a monoid into one with a flipped `mappend`:

```
composeParts :: (Category cat) => [cat a a] -> cat a a
composeParts = appEndo . getDual . mconcat . map (Dual . Endo)
```

This demonstrates that `composeParts` is a "well-defined pattern" in some sense :)

Comment: +1 I was going to give the same answer (until the edit...).  I think `composeParts` is arguably cleaner than `mysteryCombinator`.

Comment: @pat: Agreed; I would use `composeParts` directly myself.

Comment: Neat, I very much like the `foldr (>>>) id` implementation, and definitely prefer the expressive type of `(Category cat) => [cat a a] -> cat a a`.

Comment: Yeah, it's nice because it's a common operation on functions, too. I think it should be in the base libraries (along with its `(.)` equivalent); it could even be generalised to any instance of [Foldable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html): `composeParts :: (Category cat, Foldable t) => t (cat a a) -> cat a a`.

Comment: Yep, although it'd need a better name, like `flatCat` or `(>>>*)` or something :)  The only bummer about generalizing to categories is that we also need a helper to wrap and unwrap `Kleisli`s: `runKleisli $ flatCat $ map Kleisli`

Comment: Still sad, though, that this combinator doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 2):

The one starting with a non-monadic value is (modulo `flip`)

```
Prelude> :t foldr (Control.Monad.>=>) return
foldr (Control.Monad.>=>) return
    :: Monad m => [c -> m c] -> c -> m c
```

(or `foldl`)

(Yes, I know this doesn't answer the question, but the code layout in comments isn't satisfactory.)